# Select all rows or a specific row from the same stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I use the following stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetStates]
(
    @p_StateId int = NULL
)
AS
   SELECT 
      StateId AS CodeID,
      StateName AS CodeName
   FROM 
      States
   WHERE 
      StateID = COALESCE(@p_StateID, StateID)
```

If `@p_StateId` is null, it returns all rows, if not it return a single row if the `StateId` match.

My question is, do a more elegant way to achieve this exist with SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An explicit comparison with `NULL` should work as well:

```
SELECT StateId AS CodeID,
       StateName AS CodeName
FROM States
WHERE @p_StateID IS NULL OR StateID = @p_StateID
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer dasblinkenlight, Do that approach more efficient then using the Coalesce function? I'm asking the original question because I just learned the Merge statement to run an Insert/Update and was wondering if there was a similar way to make my select more efficient.

Comment: @Mario I prefer the way with an explicit `IS NULL` for slightly better readability, not for any performance gain. Although the query optimizer is more likely to figure out what's going on with an explicit `NULL` check than with `COALESCE`, good chances are that the performance is going to remain the same. If `States` represents the states of the USA, that is, if it is a table of 50 rows, a full-table scan might be just as efficient as an index lookup, because the table is so tiny. You may want to look at the query plan to see what the optimizer is doing.